# How did the Android BBC news and Pulse news apps implement the horizontal scroll view?

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, horizontalscrollview

How did the Android BBC news and Pulse news apps implement the horizontal scroll view with adapter?

There is no native Android support for horizontal scroll view with adapters. I am curious how they recycled the views.

Comment: Have you looked at this [HorizontalScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html)?

Comment: I've never used those apps, but i do know that android has regular horizontal scroll layout options available. you could probably just put your listviews in, make them horizontal and make it expand outside the screen. I can't imagine view recycling being imperative with a horizontal listview cause 50+ items on horizontal layout just seems impractical. But it'd recycle if you got it horizontal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write your own Horizontally scrollable **ViewGroup** using **AdapterView**, look into the source code of the Android's [Gallery](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.1_r2/android/widget/Gallery.java) view and modify it, it is the closest implementation you can use to get started.